# Combine PDF forms including filled-in information

Tags: pdf, pdftk, poppler

I have been trying to file my taxes by filling out the individual forms, which are fillable PDFs on the IRS's website, and concatenating them using the `pdfunite` command:

```
pdfunite f1040.pdf f1040s1.pdf f1040s3.pdf f1040sa.pdf Fed_2022_all.pdf
```

However, that results in the saved form values from each form being saved only on the first page. For instance, Form 1040 is two pages, and the form fields on page 2 are rendered uneditable. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I found Firefox could edit fillable pdf forms. Just downloaded 1040. It opened both pages & saved info on both pages. I just Kubuntu, so default is Okular, which does not work for filling info. But it opened both edited pages once saved from Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be a bug in `pdfunite`. Use the `pdftk` command instead:

```
pdftk f1040.pdf f1040s1.pdf f1040s3.pdf f1040sa.pdf cat output Fed_2022_all.pdf
```

The `pdftk` command has many options and can be used to do other things as well, such as merging selected pages from different PDF files into one PDF.

Comment: pdftk hasn't been updated in a decade, and gets hiccups on newer PDF formats

Comment: however, unlike mupdf it seems to handle saved form data. Interesting,.